# Uninitialized default constructor in c++: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

having this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;
    explicit Foo(size_t size) :size(size){
        ar = new double[size];
    }
    Foo(std::initializer_list<double> initList): Foo(initList.size()){
        std::copy(initList.begin(), initList.end(), ar);
    }
    Foo(double *values, size_t size):size(size), ar(values){}
    Foo(const Foo &rhs): Foo(rhs.size){
        std::copy(rhs.ar, rhs.ar+size, ar);
    }
    ~Foo(){delete[] ar;}
    Foo &operator=(Foo rhs){
        swap(*this, rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    void print(){
        std::copy(ar, ar+size, std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    size_t size;
    double *ar;

    static void swap(Foo &f, Foo &s){
        std::swap(f.size, s.size);
        std::swap(f.ar, s.ar);
    }
};

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    size_t size = 100;
    auto *values = new double[size];
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
        double fraction = ((10+i) % 10) / 10.0;
        values[i] = i + fraction;
    }

    Foo f(values, size);
    // Foo g; //IF THIS IS NOT BRACED-INITIALIZED, I GOT munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
    Foo g{};
    g = f;
    g.print();
}
```

The only difference between the programing running and getting error is whether I initilize the `Foo g` with braces or not. Why is that important. I know the braces will **value**-initialize the class, which means the `int *ar` would be `nullptr`.  If it is not brace-initialized, then the `int *ar` is **indeterminate**. But what does that mean? How could be pointer indeterminate? Is it the same as `nullptr`? And why does the program break, when the pointer is indeterminate?

Comment: The default constructor leaves `ar` and `size` uninitialised.

Comment: @RichardCritten what that means, and why is that causing error and value-initialised doesn't?

Comment: It means that the members have no known value. `size` could be zero. It could be 4 billion. There's no way to know. There's also no way to know where `ar` points. Most of the time it will be somewhere hopelessly invalid and the program will crash, but what it it just happens to point at the middle of the program's stack? That's a perfectly legal place to point, but writing through that pointer will trash some other part of the program, and that's a <expletive deleted> to debug.

Comment: When the uninitialised `Foo` goes out of scope, its destructor is called and `delete[] ar;` will try and delete random memory as `ar` was never initialised.

Comment: @RichardCritten No, `g=f` would assign `g` with a properly initialized object, so everything should be ok in dtor. Seems like the OP is running a debug build that catches an assignment to uninitialized variables is the assignment operator. One thing is clear: the class is buggy - ctor = default is wrong here.

Comment: @Eugene the temporary created when calling `operator=` is now carrying the bomb.

Comment: @RichardCritten yes, your corrected comment is right. Would you like to answer the question and explain this to the OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is not brace-initialized, then the `int *ar` is **indeterminate**. But what does that mean? How could be pointer indeterminate?

Because you are not assigning *any* value to the pointer, not even `nullptr`.  So its value will consist of whatever random bytes were already stored in the memory location that the pointer is occupying.

When a default constructor is declared with `= default`, that just means the compiler will implicitly generate a constructor that will default-initialize each class member for you.  Any member that is a class type will have its default constructor called, and any member that is a non-class type will either have its default value assigned **if such a value is explicitly specified**, or else **it will not be assigned any value at all**.  The latter is what is happening in your situation.

> Is it the same as nullptr?

No.

> And why does the program break, when the pointer is indeterminate?

Because the pointer is not pointing at valid memory, so any attempt to dereference the pointer to access the pointed memory will fail.  Including your destructor, which is unconditionally calling `delete[]` on the pointer, which is safe to do *only* if the pointer is set to `nullptr` or is pointing at *valid* memory that was `new[]`'ed.

In your case, you should add default values for your non-class type members, eg:

```cpp
private:
    size_t size = 0;
    double *ar = nullptr;
```

That way, if *any* constructor does not explicitly set values to them, the compiler will still assign their default values to them. In this case, `Foo() = default;` will generate an implicit default constructor that is roughly equivalent to:

`Foo() : size(0), ar(nullptr) {}`

---

You are also missing a move constructor. Your existing `operator=` assignment operator acts sufficiently as a copy assignment operator, but adding a move constructor will allow it to also act as a sufficient move assignment operator, eg:

```cpp
Foo(Foo &&rhs): size(rhs.size), ar(rhs.ar){
    rhs.ar = nullptr;
    rhs.size = 0;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
Foo(Foo &&rhs){
    size = std::exchange(rhs.size, 0);
    ar = std::exchange(rhs.ar, nullptr);
}
```

Or:

```cpp
Foo(Foo &&rhs): Foo(){
    swap(*this, rhs);
}
```

---

Also, your `Foo(double*, size_t)` constructor is broken.  It is *taking ownership* of the passed in `double*` pointer, which is not guaranteed to be `new[]`'ed so the destructor can safely `delete[]` it.

This constructor needs to allocate its own `double[]` array and *copy the source values* into it, just like the `Foo(std::initializer_list)` constructor is doing, eg:

```cpp
Foo(const double *values, size_t size): Foo(size) {
    std::copy(values, values+size, ar);
}
```

---

That all being said, a much better and safer design would be to replace your manual `double[]` array with `std::vector` instead, and let it handle all of the memory management and copy/move operations for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;
    explicit Foo(size_t size) : ar(size){}
    Foo(std::initializer_list<double> initList) : ar(initList){}
    Foo(const double *values, size_t size) : ar(values, values+size){}

    // compiler-generated copy/move constructors, copy/move assignment operators,
    // and destructor will suffice, so no need to declare them explicitly...

    void print() const {
        std::copy(ar.cbegin(), ar.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::vector<double> ar;
};
```

Comment: Note : we can add `const` to the constructor taking pointer as there is no longer ownership transfer.